# Total price doesn't update immediately when i change quantity of item in cart - MERN

Tags: reactjs

When I update my item quantity in cart it updates at the same time with the quantity in the database however the total price doesn't change until i refresh the page

this contains the cart items that is displayed into the cart page
it needs to be refreshed everytime i try to update the quantity of items

```
const Cart = () => {

 

  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const[Total,setTotal] = useState(0)
  const userID = useGetUserID()


 

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCartitems = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:5174/cart/getcart/${userID}`
        );
        setCartItems(response.data.cartItems);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    

    fetchCartitems(); 
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Calculate total price whenever cart items change
    const updatedTotalPrice = cartItems.reduce((total, item) => {
      return total + item.price * item.quantity;
    },0);
    setTotal(updatedTotalPrice);
  }, [cartItems]);

let totalPrice = 0;


  return (
    <div className='container px-10 flex'>
      <div className="">
      <h2 className='py-6'>My Cart</h2>
      <ul className='space-y-3'>
 
        {cartItems.map(item => (
          <CartItem key={item.productId} productId={item.productId} title={item.name} price={item.price} quantity={item.quantity} imgs={item.imgs}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="">
      {Total}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  

}


const CartItem = (props) => {
  const [qty, setqty] = useState(props.quantity)


  const decreaseQuantity = async (productId, quantity) => {
    try {
     
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5174/cart/updatecart", {
        productId,
        quantity: qty - 1,
        userID: useGetUserID(),
      });
      
      if(qty > 1){
        setqty(qty => qty - 1)
        
      }
     
    console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      
      console.error(err.response.data);
    }
  }
  const increaseQuantity = async (productId, quantity) => {
    try {
     
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5174/cart/updatecart", {
        productId,
        quantity: qty + 1,
        userID: useGetUserID(),
      });
      
      if(qty >= 1){
        setqty(qty => qty + 1)
      }
     
    console.log(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      
      console.error(err.response.data);
    }
  }
  

 
  return (
    <div className='flex space-x-3 font-Inter'>
      <div className="">
      <img src={props.imgs} alt="" className='w-32 h-32 rounded-md'/>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
      <h1 className='font-bold text-xl'>{props.title}</h1>
        <h1>{props.price}</h1>
       
        <div className="flex">
        <button className='border border-b-2 px-3 rounded-tl-md rounded-bl-md' onClick={() =>decreaseQuantity(props.productId,props.quantity)}>-</button>
        <h1 className='px-2'>{qty}</h1>
        <button className='border border-b-2 px-3 rounded-tr-md rounded-br-md' onClick={() =>increaseQuantity(props.productId,props.quantity)}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  )
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated thanks a lot